# Is there a way to turn off forcing dark mode in an my app programatically?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app with a dark mode and a light mode set. If I try to launch an app on my Xiaomi device with dark mode and dark mode set in the individual apps settings it darkens the colors even more than specified in my theme.kt. It doesn't happen on the emulator, just on my phone. I know it happens because Xiaomi phones override the light theme and create their own dark mode. If I turn the individual dark mode off it displays correctly. How do I make it not possible for Xiaomi phones to force dark mode?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66923051/2808493) would help you.

Comment: @Armin isn't it a bad practice to define theme in themes.xml instead of theme.kt when using jetpack compose?

Comment: Ok check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70105736/2808493) too. It's using jetpack compose.

Comment: I have already had this setup, doesn't work.